# Is the grey line the mean or the median?

Tags: statistics, sas-jmp

On this JMP plot

[image]

found [here](http://www.jmp.com/academic/pdf/learning/02_box_plots.pdf)

Does the horizontal grey line represent the overall mean or median (or something else)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a graph.

Comment: The question was off-topic as well on cross-validated. And there are many graph-related questions on stack but I understand that my question has no underlying programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The gray line shows the **survival plot** on your diagram.

> When you select Show Points and Show Combined, the survival plot for the total or combined sample appears as a gray line. The points also appear at the plot steps of each group.

http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Survival_Platform_Options.shtml

See also: http://www.jmp.com/support/help/The_Survival_Plot.shtml